# How can i avoid this error in my python code

Tags: python, python-2.7

My program takes the following input 
1. The hour which I arrive
2. Number of movies(n) 
3. Last n lines the movies with their respective hours price and name:

Example:

```
18:00
4
12:34 16 Overlord
18:40 15 Bohemian-Rhapsody
19:20 19 Elliot-O
21:22 21 Venom
```

And for the output it needs to give the movie which is closer to my arriving hour. I turned the hours in minutes with the code below but I am getting the below error:

```
hours=movie.split(' ')[0].split(':')[0]
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I tried  replacing split(':') with strip(':') , same error

```
movie=[]
for i in range(nr_movies):
    movies.append(raw_input)

dictionary_movies={}
for movie in movies:
    hour=movie.split(' ')[0].split(':')[0]
    minutes=movie.split(' ')[0].split(':')[1]
    price=int(movie.split(' ')[1])
    name=str(movie.split(' ')[2])
    #transform in minutes
    timestamp_movie=int(hours)*60+int(minutes)
    difference=timestamp_movie - timestamp
```

Comment: I'll note, once you finish this program and get it working, you can post it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and we can make improvement suggestions there. I see a few things that could be cleaned up, like not repeatedly splitting the same string over and over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the list of functions `raw_input`, not real inputs.

Replace this:

`movies.append(raw_input)`

with this:

`movies.append(raw_input())`

Answer (score 1):

```
# Consider these are the input values
arriving_hour = "18:00"
movies=[
    "12:34 16 Overlord",
    "18:40 15 Bohemian-Rhapsody",
    "19:20 19 Elliot-O",
    "21:22 21 Venom"
]

diff = []
for movie in movies:
    hour=movie.split(' ')[0].split(':')[0]
    minutes=movie.split(' ')[0].split(':')[1]
    price=int(movie.split(' ')[1])
    name=str(movie.split(' ')[2])
    timestamp_movie=int(hour)*60+int(minutes)
    arriving_minutes = int(arriving_hour[0:2])*60+int(arriving_hour[3:5])
    difference = abs(timestamp_movie - arriving_minutes)
    diff.append(difference)

min_diff = min(diff)
min_diff_index = diff.index(min_diff)

# This movie is closer to arriving hour
movies[min_diff_index]
```